# Retrieve radiogroup selection from sharedpreferences in another activity?

Tags: android

I've looked and tried different methods so im definitely doing something wrong.

I have a radiogroup selection in the main activity of either "pounds" or "kilograms". Whichever radio they select should change to that text in the next activity.

Lbs is the current default radio and that is checked as "true".

I have placed a button in the 2nd activity to go BACK to the radio selection screen. However, after selecting "kgs", it continues to display "lbs".

Main Activity

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String enteredWeightState = sharedPreferences.getString("entered_weight", "");
    int lbsState = sharedPreferences.getInt("UOM_checkId", UOM_RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    UOM_RadioGroup.check(lbsState);
    enter_weight_editText.setText(enteredWeightState);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    UOM_RadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.UOM_RadioGroup);
    enter_weight_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_weight_editText);

    UOM_RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup UOM_RadioGroup, int checkedId) {

            if (checkedId == R.id.UOM_pounds) {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("UOM_checkId", checkedId);
                editor.apply();

            } else {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("UOM_checkId", checkedId);
                editor.apply();
            }

        }

    });
}


    public void beginRoutineButton(View view) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("entered_weight", enter_weight_editText.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}



Activity2

    public TextView unit_of_measure;
    public View fragment1;
    public Button backButton;
    public TextView weight;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        weight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        unit_of_measure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unit_of_measure);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int lbsState = sharedPreferences.getInt("UOM_checkId", -1);
        String enteredWeightState = sharedPreferences.getString("entered_weight", "");


        weight.setText(enteredWeightState);


        if (lbsState < 0)
            unit_of_measure.setText("kgs");
        else
            unit_of_measure.setText("lbs");


    }


    public void backButton(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class named as SharedPreferences and in that make a method init and initialise preferences there see below:-

```
public class SharedPreferences{
    private static Context mContext;
    private static SharedPreferences preferences = null;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static void init(Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences.mContext = Env.appContext;
        SharedPreferences.preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("user_info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.editor = preferences.edit();
    }
}
```

and call init method of SharedPreferences in launcher activity as `SharedPreferences.init()` and make getter setter in preferences like below:-

```
public static void setWeight(String weight){
editor.putString("entered_weight", weight).commit();
}

public static String getWeight(){
 return preferences.getString("entered_weight", null);
}
```

and when you want to set weight call `SharedPreferences.setWeight(ed.getText.toString());` and get value using `SharedPreferences.getWeight();`. You can get value from any where inside the application the only thing you have to do is call `init()` method on launcher activity and use saving value and getting value inside sharedPreferences.

Do like above it will help you out.